# Javascript form validation not working in IE-7,8 browser

Tags: javascript, html

I have a one web to display car comparison and i am doing a form validation using javascript but validation properly works in Mozila firefox, chrome browser but in IE-7,8 its not working.

The code is as follows:-
JS Code:-

```
function chk(){
var b1=document.getElementById("txtbrand1").value;
var m1=document.getElementById("txtmodel1").value;
var v1=document.getElementById("txtvariant1").value;
var b2=document.getElementById("txtbrand2").value;
var m2=document.getElementById("txtmodel2").value;
var v2=document.getElementById("txtvariant2").value;


if(b1=='')
{
      document.getElementById('brand1_err').style.display = 'block';
      return false;
}else if(m1=='Car Model'){
    //alert('Please select car 1 model.');
    document.getElementById('model1_err').style.display = 'block';
    return false;
}else if(v1=='Car Variant'){
    //alert('Please select car 1 variant.');
    document.getElementById('variant1_err').style.display = 'block';
    return false;
}else if(b2==''){
    //alert('Please select car 2 brand.');
    document.getElementById('brand2_err').style.display = 'block';
    return false;
}else if(m2=='Car Model'){
    //alert('Please select car 2 model.');
    document.getElementById('model2_err').style.display = 'block';
    return false;
}else if(v2=='Car Variant'){
    //alert('Please select car 2 variant.');
    document.getElementById('variant2_err').style.display = 'block';
    return false;
}else if(b1==b2 && m1==m2 && v1==v2){
    //alert('Please select two different cars.');
    document.getElementById('samecar_err').style.display = 'block';
    return false;
}else{
return true;
}
```

}

Form Code:-

```
<form action="admin/pdf/create_result.php" method="post" name="frmcompare" id="frmcompare" onsubmit="return chk();">
```

Form contains 6 fields Car-Name-1, Car-Brand-1, Car-varient-1, Car-Name-2, Car-Brand-2, Car-varient-2.

if you have any solution please share it with me.thanks in advance.

Comment: What means not working??? Any error in console? Why question is tagged with jQuery? Obviously, you are not using it

Comment: I mean without validation it submit the form.

Comment: So check which part of validation is failing. You should debug it on your side and see what's going on

Answer (score 0):

Try checking in the button's `onclick` instead of the form's `onsubmit`. Something like this

```
<form action="admin/pdf/create_result.php" method="post" name="frmcompare" id="frmcompare">
  ...
  ...
  <input type="button" name="Compare" value="Compare" onclick="chk();">
</form>
<script>
  function chk(){
    ...
    ...
    document.getElementById("frmcompare").submit();
  }
</script>
```

If you'd rather do it in the form's `onsubmit`, then you have to cancel the event properly and support all browsers. Try replacing all lines `return false;` in your `chk()` function with the following:

```
if(event.preventDefault){
    event.preventDefault();
}else{
   event.returnValue = false;
}
return false;
```

alternatively, you can place this code in another function, let's say `CancelSubmit()` and change all those `return false;` lines to `return CancelSubmit();`.

Comment: I've just tried it in IE and it worked perfectly. Make sure you are using `type=button` not `type=submit`.

Comment: what if I submit the form by pressing "enter" instead of clicking a submit button?

Comment: @Kos That will bypass the validation, but your server code must do the validation again in all cases, so it will catch it and return the appropriate error to the user. JavaScript validation is just to enhance the user experience, but does not replace the server validation. Anyway, if you still want to enhance a bit more and support the enter key, then you have to either validate the form's `onsubmit`, on use a submit button and validate the button's `onclick`. In both cases you have to cancel the event properly, not just by `return false`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of if(b1=='') use length property

```
if(b1.length===0)
```

I think it s always going into first one and other validations are not working in IE.

Comment: If it is always going to the first `if` like you said, then it is always returning `false`, which in turn means the form never gets submitted. This is not what the OP described in his comment "I mean without validation it submit the form". What he said means it is either reaching the `return true;` all the time, or never calling the `chk()` function at all.

Comment: @RacilHilan got it. My bad that I skipped that part accidentally

Comment: but why it happens in only IE -7,8? in other browser it works fine

Comment: @CRMDevelopement I cannot tell for sure without seeing the code for your submit button, but the issue is not with IE per se. It is how events propagate in HTML. Returning `false` will cancel the button's `onclick` event, but the submit event is not cancelled. To cancel it, you need to use things like `event.preventDefault` and `event.returnValue = false`, but then you run into browser compatibility. Instead of trying to support all browser, use the alternative solution that I suggested in my answer. It is much simpler and will work in all browsers.